# Simple windows software that just display the command line

Tags: windows

I look for a tiny software that simply display its command line in an inputbox so that it can be copied.

I have programmed it with Windev because it's very trivial to do but this IDE generate a very big executable (~20 Mo)...

So I search a similar and tiny program for that.

Comment: The command line of your own program?

Comment: Imagine this program is named foo.exe. I launch foo.exe commandline_test. I want a simple inputbox that show : commandline_test.
So that I can copy it to inject in a program i develop.

Comment: So you compile a program `foo.exe` and start it passing `commandline_test` as parameter and you want it to show a messagebox displaying `commandline_test`. Do I have that right? I only ask because I fail to see what's the purpose of such a program?!